# Почему дублируется часть адреса в URL после повторного перехода по ссылке?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть несколько страниц с урл из `RewriteRule`
Например:

```
mysite.com/blog/   
mysite.com/blog/review/   
mysite.com/mainpage/
```

И есть правила в htaccess:

```
RewriteRule  blog$      index.php?pagename=blog [L]  
RewriteRule  blog/review-([0-9]{1,7}+)$  index.php?pagename=blog&postid=$1   [L]  
RewriteRule  mainpage$      index.php   [L]
```

И есть правила для разных языков

```
RewriteRule ^lang/(.*)/$  index.php?pagename=main&lang=$1
```

И ссылки-якоря в тегах сделаны такого вида: `href="lang/en/"`.
Это сделано, чтобы при выборе языков все страницы были построены следующим образом:

```
mysitecom/lang/en/blog  
mysitecom/lang/en/blog/review
```

Что, собственно говоря, и происходит, и вроде работает, но есть один глюк: если нажать два раза на языки, переходит по такому адресу:

```
mysitecom/lang/en/lang/en
```

Кто знает, как это исправить?

Comment: Если все языки двумя буквами кодируются, то можно попробовать `RewriteRule ^lang/(\w{2})/$ index.php?pagename=main&lang=$1`

Comment: там тремя тоже наверно будет но я сделал как вы сказали это никак не помогает решить вопрос с тем что языки появляются друг за другом при каждом нажатии - mysitecom/lang/en/lang/en/lang/en/lang/en/lang/en/lang/en

Comment: Из описания я не совсем понимаю какой запрос в итоге приходит. Может быть просто слэш в начале добавить href="/lang/en/" ?

Comment: но ведь тогда переходит в верхний узел

Comment: в смысле папкой выше в родительскую директорию

Comment: в родительскую директорию это двоеточие "../", а слэш означает "от корня"

Comment: в целом проблема с которой я завис в том что часть с языками повторяется из за последнего слеша то есть mysitecom/lang/en/lang/en должен при уже выбраннном языке стать таким mysitecom/lang/en/ но это происходит только если переделать без слешей но тогда последующие части не идут после языков(((

Comment: да наверно вы правы. просто локально переходит в сам локалхост

Comment: глобально все работает спасибо вам огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Это все решается не кучей правил в `.htaccess`, а всего одним правилом, которое ВСЕ запросы направляет на роутер (в Вашем случае им и так выступает `index.php`).

Все запросы обрабатываются исключительно роутером и он определяет какой скрипт должен сработать.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```